# Dataset input when combining models in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, concatenation, pytorch-dataloader

I have two deep learning `Models A and B`, `B` is trained separately with the prediction results of `A`. To train the `B Model`, I want to use the prediction result of `A` as `B`'s input. It can be understood as concatenation of the two models. So when I write the Dataset of `Model B` in PyTorch, it read data from the `Model A` rather than the local file. However, when train the `Model B`, it's very slow since `Model A` needs to be run for every input data of `Model B`, is there any efficient way to combine two models? I am trying to save the prediction data of `model A` as files, and then read the files as `B`'s dataset input, this takes a lot of storage, maybe not the best way. Looking forward to ideas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're backpropagating loss only through model B, it should take only roughly 2x time to do the forward pass through both models, and the backwards pass should take the same time regardless of whether the inputs to model B are loaded from file cache or directly from model A. Importantly, you need to disable gradient computation for model A, or model A will be rather slow and backpropagation will be slow. Your code should roughly look like:

```
for batch in dataset:
    input_A, target_B = batch
    modelA.eval()
    
    # ensure no gradient computation for model A
    with torch.no_grad():
         output_A = modelA(input_A)
         output_A = output_A.detatch() # ensure backpropagation will stop here

    # gradient computation as normal
    output_B = modelB(output_A)
    loss = loss_fn(output_B,target_B)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that the batch size should be the same of the two models. What if there is another output_C using the output_A as input, which is not a deep learning model? If code like your proposed, whether output_C should also output the same batch size of data?

Comment: Yes, but it's unclear what you mean by "not a deep learning model". If you are not learning trainable weights in this model, then there is no need to include it during training at all.

Comment: Exactly! So I put them into the part of the dataset, not the training process. Following your code, I'll try to add the non-trainable model (called model C) after the output_A as `output_C = function(output_A)` under the `with torch.no_grad()`, and modify `output_B = modelB(output_C)`, hope it works.